# ¿Como conectarme a un servidor SQL (ya poseo VPN)?

Tags: sql-server

¿Como puedo acceder a un servidor SQL Server remota(no local) cuando ya estoy en una VPN?

¿Debo de realizar configuraciones antes de que se me habilite el acceso?

Es decir ya tengo las credenciales del server

Server:  IP\XXXXXX

User

Password

Al momento de ingresar las credenciales en SQL Server me manda error

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to 192.168.0.40\XXXXXXXXX

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

No se puede abrir la base de datos predeterminada del usuario. Error de inicio de sesión.
Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'rsaez'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Comment: tienes ping al servidor o ip: 192.168.0.40 si no consigues tener ping entonces nisiquieras estas alcansando el Hierro(Hardware) por ende debe haber un problema relacionado a la red o configuracion de la misma o de firewall... que lamentablemente seria off topic del sitio SOes.

Comment: Si puedo hacer ping pero el problema

Comment: pero el problema que??? no será entonces el firewall??? lo que yo veo es que el servidor dice que no puede abrir la base de datos para el usuario que especificas y escupe un error de acceso 4046... estas seguro que el usuario tiene los accessos necesarios???

Comment: El problema persiste xd

Comment: si y que probaste ???

Comment: Configurar el firewall con reglas de entrada y salida.

Comment: ok prueba con otro programa a ver si tienes accesos con ese usuario a esa base de datos ...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu espíritu de servicio. Lo probare :D.

Comment: PUDE INGRESAR, no tenias permisos otorgados por el admin de la BD